# Minimum distance estimator

Tags: nonlinear-regression

I'm trying to replicate the paper of Blundell et al. (2008) to separate permanent and transitory shocks on income on a panel dataset.
He solves the non-linear system of equations using Chamberlain's minimum distance estimator (it is shown in the appendix of the paper), but I haven't found a library, nor in R, nor in STATA, that does the trick. Can someone help me?

Comment: please add link to the article

Comment: Google Scholar finds 229 papers authored in 2008 by a Blundell. Could you give us a bit more of a clue to which one you are referring, or maybe a URI?

Comment: I would guess it was [Blundell, R., Pistaferri, L. and Preston, I. (2008). "Consumption inequality and partial insurance", American Economic Review, 98(5), pp. 1887-1921.](http://gatton.uky.edu/Faculty/Ziliak/Blundell_Pistaferri_Preston_aer2008.pdf), though there are more possibilities [here](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/~uctp39a/pub.html)

Answer (score -1):

Check the [actuar package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/actuar/index.html) or the [fitdistrplus package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fitdistrplus/index.html) vignettes.